# push operation on stack using linked list fails

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I am trying to create a stack using single linked list, my push operation doesn't insert data into the linked list

This is what I have tried so far,

```
typedef struct element {
    int data;
    struct element *next;
}node;
```

The push method

```
void push(node *root, int data) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = (node *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
        root->data = data;
        root->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        node *temp = (node *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = root;
        root = temp;
    }
}
```

In my main method, I haven't `malloc`ed the head pointer, 
and this is how I call the push method,

```
push(head, data);
```

How can I make the push operation work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `root` pointer is modified in the `push` function. This value is not propagated to `main`. One way to do it is to return the `root` pointer.

```
node* push(node *root, int data) {
  if(root == NULL) {
    root = (node *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
    root->data = data;
    root->next = NULL;
  }
  else {
    node *temp = (node *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = root;
    root = temp;
  }
  return root;
}
```

And in main, you need to call it like,

```
head = push(head, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `root` value is a pointer, but the address is passed **by value**, meaning that if you modify the address, it will have **no side effect** outside the scope of the function.

Use:

```
void push(node **root, int data )
```

To be able to modify the value of root

and:

```
push( &head, data )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problematic line of code:

```
root = temp;
```

You are assigning a local `node*` called `root` to another local `node*` called `temp`, but this assignment is not "sticking" outside of the `push()` function.  To make it stick, you can dereference as follows:

```
*root = *temp;
```

Full code:

```
void push(node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (node *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
        root->data = data;
        root->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        node *temp = (node *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = root;
        *root = *temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of duplicating code.

As others have responded, your function needs to return the pointer to the malloc()'d buffer...

And, we can use 'root' to our advantage, NULL or not...

```
node_t *push( node_t *root, int data ) {
    node_t *np = (node_t *) malloc( sizeof(node_t) );
    np->data = data;
    np->next = root;
    return np;
}
```

The "_t" suffix used above is a convention to help distinguish the name of a datatype from a variable name.