# Inserting Node Linked List C

Tags: c, printing, linked-list, insertion

I am trying to create a linked list which stores name and age of a student.
I am having trouble with insertion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{

  char Name[50];
  int studentAge;
  struct node* next;

}MyNode;
```

this is how i defined my Struct which constains the requried data and a pointer 'next' which points to the next node.

Below is my insertion function
so in the first if condition i am saying if there isnt a head ie head = NULL then create memory space for the head using malloc.. after this i copy all the data into the head node and making sure that the next of head points to null.

In the second condition i am saying if there is a head ie Head ! = NULL
then traverse the list to the end using the current pointer and then copy all the data in.

```
void InsertStudent(char givenName[50], int age, MyNode* head){

    if(head == NULL){
        head = (MyNode*) malloc(sizeof(MyNode));
        strcpy(head->Name,givenName);
        head->studentAge = age;
        head->next = NULL;
    }


    if(head != NULL){
        MyNode* current = head;
            while(current->next != NULL){
                current = current->next;
            }
        current->next = (MyNode*) malloc(sizeof(MyNode));
        strcpy(current->next->Name,givenName);
        current->next->studentAge = age;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }

}
```

Now i am not sure if there is a problem in my printing or inserting because it doesn't print my nodes when i try the code out

```
void PrintList(MyNode* head){
    MyNode* current = head;

    while(current != NULL){
        printf("Name is %s Age is %d\n",current->Name,current->studentAge);
        current = current->next;
    }

}
```

this is my main function.. is there a problem with the MyNode* head = NULL; line of code is that allowed?

```
  int main()
   {


    MyNode* head = NULL;

    int r = 0;
while(r!=1)
    {
    printf("Data Structures - Linked List\n");
    printf("Choose one Option:\n\n");
    printf("1.Insert Student\n");
    printf("2.Remove Student\n");
    printf("3.Print all student\n");
    printf("4.Exit\n");

        int option=0;
        char givenName[50];
        int givenAge;
        scanf("%d",&option);

        switch(option){

        case 1:
        printf("Enter name of student:     ");
        scanf("%s",givenName);
        printf("\nEnter Age of student:    ");
        scanf("%d",&givenAge);
        InsertStudent(givenName,givenAge,head);
            break;

        case 2:
        printf("Enter name of student:     ");
        scanf("%s",givenName);
        printf("\nEnter Age of student:    ");
        scanf("%d",&givenAge);
        RemoveStudent(givenName,givenAge);
            break;

        case 3:
        PrintList(head);
            break;
        case 4:
        r=1;
            break;
        default:
        r=1;
        printf("\nNot an option\n");
            break;

       }

    }
}
```

Comment: `head = (MyNode*) malloc(sizeof(MyNode))` in `InsertStudent` means *nothing* to the caller of that function. The `head` pointer is passed by value. Assigning to it as such just modifies a local variable; the caller's pointer remains unchanged. Either utilize the otherwise-unused return value of the function to communicate a possibly-updated head pointer, or pass the head pointer by *address* (so a pointer-to-pointer) and change the code in `InsertStudent` accordingly. There are at least a thousand duplicates of this problem on SO. I'll try and hunt one down.

Comment: Found one [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982512/push-operation-on-stack-using-linked-list-fails). The first and second answers actually demonstrate both methods I described above.

Comment: from what i have seen, are you trying to suggesting to either change void Insert(..) to MyNode* insert(...) and return the new node...   or the second method is to use void ( double pointer)... is that what your saying?  i would like to go with double pointers as that seems harder but i don't really know how to do it..

Comment: The comment I posted, in conjunction with the answer and prior question I linked, cannot possibly describe better what needs to be done. The second answer in the linked question shows *precisely* how to do this with pointer-to-pointer syntax.

Comment: thanks. ill fix it now. i just saw ur second post so i didnt know you linked an example

Comment: Adding to what WhozCraig said, consider defining a type `List` to be a pointer `MyNode*` and using that instead. This makes it easier to understand what is going on, in my opinion. If you call `InsertStudent(name, age, list)` none of the three arguments will come out with a different value, including the pointer `list`. If `list` was null before the call it will be null after the call.

Comment: JorgeAdriano i don't really understand what your saying... i'm new to pointers.      @WhozCraig  i changed it to   Insert(name,age, MyNode** head) and input is   Insert(name,age,&head)   but now i am getting errors with strcpy(head->name,givenname) and head->studentage = age   i'm not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the initial value of the head pointer to the first node, and since that is never done, the list remains empty and you leak memory like a sieve leaks rain water.

As you have communicated you want to use pointer-to-pointer syntax, the result should look like this . (sans error checking, which you shoudl probably consider adding):

```
void InsertStudent(char givenName[50], int age, MyNode** head)
{
    while (*head)
        head = &(*head)->next;

    *head = malloc(sizeof **head);
    strcpy((*head)->Name, givenName);
    (*head)->studentAge = age;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
```

Invoked from your main program using the address of the head pointer (do NOT confused that with the address held *in* the head pointer which you're initially setting to NULL correctly; think of the latter a value held by a pointer, the former as a residence where the head pointer itself is in memory).

```
InsertStudent(givenName,givenAge, &head); // NOTE THIS
```

I leave the task of removal and list cleanup.

Comment: sorry to bother you.. i dont understand what these 3 lines do:        while (*head)
                             head = &(*head)->next;            

    *head = malloc(sizeof **head);

Comment: Remember, you're passing the *address of a pointer*. It's therefore coming in as a pointer-to-pointer. if `head` in this function is a pointer to a pointer, then `*head` is the value of the pointer being pointed to. That's the original pointer in `main`. I strongly suggest you hit up some google-fu with the topic of "C pointer to pointer". or consult your text if you have one. And, as always, single stepping though this code with a debugger, watching variables as it progresses, is *extremely* educational.

Comment: in insert(**head) am i right in assuming head is actually address of head so is it ok to change head into addresshead in that function? then *addresshead will actually be head and  **addresshead would be the actual first node, it doesnt really affect the code but its confusing like this.. i am just making sure my logic is correct

Comment: It sounds like it's more or less accurate.

Comment: i kind of followed what you said and thought about it and now its working i think i slightly understand double pointers now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are passing head by value; which means that the line in InsertStudent:

```
head = (MyNode*) malloc(sizeof(MyNode))
```

which does not update the variable ‘head’ in main.
What you want is to pass &head to InsertStudent, but then InsertStudent has to deal with a MyNode **.   The other option is have InsertStudent return head, so that its invocation is:

```
 head = InsertStudent(name, age, head);
```

It doesn’t matter much either way, some people prefer the latter because it looks more *functional*.

Inside of InsertStudent, you add the first element twice.   This is almost certainly unwanted.   By the time you get to the line:

```
if(head != NULL){
```

head is never NULL; if it were, you would have assigned it in the if statement above.   You probably want this statement to be:

```
else {
```